# Electron specified procedure could not be found

Tags: electron, realm, electron-builder

Application is working fine on my system but on client system it is showing this issue.
[image]

Technologies used :

1. Angular v8
2. Electron v4.1.4
3. Realm v3.0.0

Comment: Why do you want to use a mobile database in desktop application?

Comment: @TienDuong I am using it as embedded DB

Comment: I see. Can you upload your `package.json`?

Comment: @TienDuong Please review package.json here : https://github.com/jindalrohit/electron-app/blob/master/package.json